# How to copy proccess's memory pages to a buffer?(kernel space)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

My goal is to copy each page of a chosen process to a `buffer` whose size is a `page`.

I've ran in some difficulties, since I want to choose which process to read the memory from, it's not necessarily `'current' task_struct`. 
So if I copy the memory from a `task_struct` of my choice, the `MMU` won't 
link me to the correct physical pages.

Any thoughts?
thank you.

Comment: Is it giving you the virtual address? Do you need to convert from virtual to physical?

Comment: Usually the buffer won't be large enough. The virtual address space of a typical process is quite big

Comment: I'm not allocating a buffer sized 4GB. the buffer's size will be the same as a page size, i just want to iterate over pages.

Comment: Isn't virtual memory designed specifically to avoid this kind of things?

Comment: @UmNyobe well, yeah. but i still need to do it :p